# Why are ID and TIMESTAMP declared as transient headers in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-messaging, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-amqp

I'm trying to send/receive messages via Spring Integration's AMQP in/outbound adapters and I'm facing [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478775/rabbitmq-failed-message-being-reprocessed-in-an-infinite-loop).

After finding Gary's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479469), I started to investigate if my app sets a message ID correctly. In fact, it's taken care of automatically [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/MessageHeaders.java#L125).

The producer looks like [this](https://github.com/springuni/springuni-forgetme/blob/master/forgetme-datahandler/src/main/java/com/springuni/forgetme/datahandler/service/WebhookServiceImpl.java#L43).

I send a wrong message on purpose and at the consumer's end I watch its message transformer fail [here](https://github.com/springuni/springuni-forgetme/blob/master/forgetme-adapters/forgetme-adapter-mailerlite/src/main/java/com/springuni/forgetme/datahandler/adapter/mailerlite/MailerLiteWebhookDataTransformer.java#L66).

After that the message gets re-queued and re-processed again endlessly.

*While debugging this issue, I noticed that the ID of the sent and received messages are always different.*

After debugging this event further, I learned that the standard ID field provided by Spring's core messaging framework is marked as transient and [transient headers are never getting mapped](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mapping/AbstractHeaderMapper.java#L65).

**Questions?**

- Why couldn't the framework automatically map `MessageHeaders.ID` to `AmqpHeaders.MESSAGE_ID`?
- Should I mandate a custom headers field as an ID and implement `MessageKeyGenerator`?
- BTW, how would I do that with the new Java DSL?

Many thanks!

Cheers,
László

---

**UPDATE:** the cause of failed message being reprocessed in an infinite loop was caused by something else.

I've managed to fix that, by adding `defaultRequeueRejected(false)` to the AMQP inbound adapter's listener container config.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow webhookInboundFlow(
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ObjectMapper objectMapper,
    HeaderValueRouter webhookInboundRouter) {

  return IntegrationFlows
      .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, FORGETME_WEBHOOK_QUEUE_NAME)
          .configureContainer(s -> s.defaultRequeueRejected(false))
      )
      .log(INFO)
      .transform(new ObjectToJsonNodeTransformer(objectMapper))
      .route(webhookInboundRouter)
      .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why couldn't the framework automatically map MessageHeaders.ID to AmqpHeaders.MESSAGE_ID?

That's not a bad idea, at least as an option. Feel free to open an 'improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Spring AMQP's `AbstractMessageConverter` has a property `createMessageIds` to generate a message id header; this is independent of Spring Integration.

So normally, if you want a message id header, you would set that property on the outbound adapter's `RabbitTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Gary! I've tried to register a custom `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` and setting that property (`createMessageIds`). Message IDs very indeed generated. Altought that broke the de-serialization of incoming messages, so I had to roll that back. As I need timestamps as well, I'll go with an overridden `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper` and I'll also open an improvement ticket.

Comment: The default message converter is a `SimpleMessageConverter` which can only handle `byte[]`, `String` or `Serializable` payloads. If you use Jackson on the producer side, you need it on the consumer side too. You can use a header-enricher on the producer side to copy the timestamp to a custom header.

Comment: Thanks again Gary! I haven't thought of the possibility of using a header-enricher. I'll go that route instead of tweaking header mappers.