# Why are the TIMESTAMP and ID headers from Spring Integration unmapped in Spring Kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Example project with a failing test is at https://github.com/phillipuniverse/kafka-headers-test.

It's odd to me that the `ID` and `TIMESTAMP` headers from Spring Integration are being removed in that they cannot be used on the receipt of the message. Is this a bug?

I came across a related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544350/why-are-id-and-timestamp-declared-as-transient-headers-in-spring-integration) that mentioned something about these headers being transient, which makes me think this behavior is intentional. Why are they transient? Why aren't these just like any other custom header which are all mapped in correctly? Is there a particular reason for the special treatment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was done for performance reasons where generation of the id and timestamp can impact performance in certain high-volume situations.

You can change the behavior with the `standardHeaders` [consumer property](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties):

> **standardHeaders**
>
> Indicates which standard headers are populated by the inbound channel adapter. Allowed values: `none`, `id`, `timestamp`, or `both`. Useful if using native deserialization and the first component to receive a message needs an id (such as an aggregator that is configured to use a JDBC message store).
>
> Default: none

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on my reading of that doc and finding the actual binding: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/properties/KafkaExtendedBindingProperties.java#L38 I would expect setting the property `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.standard-headers=both` would cause those to be mapped. Is that what you would expect to happen?

Comment: Figured it out. It binds to `KafkaExtendedBindingProperties` which has a `consumer` where `standardHeaders` needs to be set. This full property was what worked: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.standard-headers=both`

Comment: Added a PR at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pull/748 to fix the property docs